# MongoDB Aggregation query doesn't return all fields

Tags: mongodb, php-mongodb

I am trying to use the aggregation function to display info in a chart. For this example, a document in the collection looks like this (excluding unnecessary fields for this query):

```
{
 'locid' : <someid>, #Reference to a city & state collection
 'collat' : <dateobj>, #a date object when this entry was saved 
 'pid' : <someid>, #Reference to a person collection 
 'pos' : <int> #Value I am interested in matching with location & date
 }
```

So I basically start with a `pid`. I use this as my first `$match` parameter to limit the amount of data that gets thrown into the pipeline.

```
array(
    '$match' => array(
         'pid' => new \MongoId($pid)
     )
),
```

So now that I have selected the correct `pid`, I tell it I only want/need certain fields:

```
array(
    '$project' => array(
        'pos' => 1,
        'collat' => 1,
        'locid' => 1
    )
),
```

The second match is to say I only care about these locations right now (`$ids` contains an array of `locid`):

```
    array(
        '$match' => array(
            'locid' => array('$in' => $ids)
        )
    ),
```

And finally, I am saying group all the returned documents by `collat` and `locid`

```
array(
            '$group' => array(
                '_id' => array(
                    'locid' => '$locid',
                    'collat' => '$collat'
                )
            )
        )
```

While the query completes OK and returns data, I am not getting the `pos` field back, it is only returning the `locid` and `collat`.

**Questions**

1. Isn't that what `$project` is for? I use it to tell the driver what fields I want returned?
2. Once I get the `pos` field returning as well, how can I tell the driver I only want the lowest value for each `locid` & `collat` combo pair? So say there are two entries for that date, location, and person: 4 & 8. I only care about `pos`=4

My end goal is to create a line chart with the X-Axis as the dates (from `collat`) and the Y-Axis will be the `pos` field, and each line will plot individual `locid` data.

Here is the entire parameters being sent to the aggregation driver.

```
$ops = array(
        array(
            '$match' => array(
                'pid' => new \MongoId($pid)
            )
        ),
        array(
            '$project' => array(
                'pos' => 1,
                'collat' => 1,
                'locid' => 1
            )
        ),
        array(
            '$match' => array(
                'locid' => array('$in' => $ids)
            )
        ),
        array(
            '$group' => array(
                '_id' => array(
                    'locid' => '$locid',
                    'collat' => '$collat'
                )
            )
        )
    );
    $out = $myCollection->aggregate($ops);
```

**Update** This is the way I got it to group & return `pos` without throwing an error. I need to spot check it though to make sure it's actually returning the correct values though.

```
array(
            '$group' => array(
                '_id' => array(
                    'locid' => '$locid',
                    'collat' => '$collat'
                ),
                array('$min' => '$pos')
            )
        )
```

Comment: You have to specify the `pos` in the group as another field separate to the _id

Comment: @Sammaye I updated the bottom of my question. Having problems with syntax.

Comment: You might be able to specify the second part with a sort b before the group of like `{locid:-1,collat:1}` possibly though that is off the top of my head, it might work though, otherwise your gonna have hell doing that next part peformantly

Comment: As Asya said, you need to specify a type of metric for the value in the group, i.e. max or min or first or last `'pos' => {$min: '$pos'}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aggregation query is like an SQL statement `group by`.  You are telling `{$group}` what field(s) you want to 'GROUP BY' but you are not telling it how you want to aggregate the grouped information.

The `{$group}` you want is probably something like:

```
{$group : { _id : { locid: "$locid", collat: "$collat"},
            pos : {$min : "$pos"}
           }
 }
```

Comment: OK this makes sense, I knew I was missing something simple. Going to toy around with this for a minute and verify my data. Thank you!

Comment: Seems like it is working (need to spot check), just getting too much data back. Working on adding a datetime object as part of my `$match` so it only returns the past week.

Comment: Yeah I was using that, tried to do it by date range too; was using DateTime instead of MongoDate. Thanks again!